# Navit Autotools Build Without Optimization

Tags: c++, eclipse, optimization, autotools

I am trying to build an open source software system for navigation called Navit. I have successfully been able to build it within eclipse but now I am trying to use the debugger to understand how it is functioning.

I am being held back due to optimizations during compilation that aren't allowing the debugger to access a lot of the variables and other information in the system. Any idea how I disable this optimization. The program is building with autotools inside eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Use a terminal. Reconfigure and recompile with different C compiler flags:

```
make clean
./configure CFLAGS='-g -O0'
make
```

I'm sure Eclipse has a Build Configuration for this, but I wouldn't be able to tell you that off the top of my head ;-)